# Eclipse Java Selenium failed to connect to localhost

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

first I am an absolute beginner in java (hence also eclipse) and also selenium.

I need interaction with any browser for my java program (get an objekt like textfield and fill with an String). The program should ultimately do nothing else than pass information from a more diemensional String array to an internet page in the browser (so nothing completely new).
so far as the frame.
this interaction in java seems to be realized only by selenium I recently downloaded selenium. also apparently the geckodriver is needed.

this is on of the codes i tryed to start a browser. (I tryed several different browser).

Here are a few solutions that I found but did not bring any improvement.
- Update version.
- Specify string (that's why it currently looks like this: String service = "D: //IEDriverServer.exe";)

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.grid.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;


public class firefoxöffner {


        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {


            String service = "D://IEDriverServer.exe";
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", service);
            InternetExplorerDriver  driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                    driver.get("http://yahoo.com");
                    }
    }
```

following the current error code. (i removed the ip for this post).

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
3.9.0.0
Listening on port 35599
Only local connections are allowed
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:35599
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:08.638Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-BSN3U8P', ip: '', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '9.0.4'
Driver info: driver.version: InternetExplorerDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:92)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:209)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.run(InternetExplorerDriver.java:223)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:152)
    at firefoxöffner.main(firefoxöffner.java:23)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:35599
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:240)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:158)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:256)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:134)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:113)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:125)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:238)
    ... 28 more
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: Downgrading is _never_ the **solution** it's a **compromise**. We must act accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks it is known issue, please down grade IEDriverServer and try. Have look https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5519